# Select concrete DOM element without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm typing a login or password, tooltip appears with one or more sentences.
Every tooltip has **the same z-index**, but **I want to change it to higher** when I'm **focused** at adequate input and **bring it back at blur event**, but I might have 10 inputs with many options in tooltip. Is it possible to write function without using ID of tooltip?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').focus(function() {
    $('div.tooltip').addClass("active");
  });

  $('input').blur(function() {
    $('div.tooltip').removeClass("active");
  });

  $('#login').keyup(function() {
    var th = document.getElementById('login').value;
    if (th.length < 6) {
      $('#result').css('display', 'inline');
      var ex = $("#too_short").text();
      if (!ex) {
        $('#result').append('<p id="too_short">Too short password.</p>');

      }
    } else {
      $("#too_short").remove();
    }

    if (th.contains('\'') || th.contains('\"') || th.contains('\\') || th.contains('\/')) {
      $('#result').css('display', 'inline');
      var en = $("#forb_char").text();
      if (!en) {
        $('#result').append('<p id="forb_char">Forbidden characters</p>');

      }
    } else {
      $("#forb_char").remove();
    }

  });

  $('#pwd').keyup(function() {
    var th = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    if (th.length < 6) {
      $('#result1').css('display', 'inline');
      var ex = $("#too_short1").text();
      if (!ex) {
        $('#result1').append('<p id="too_short1">Too short password.</p>');

      }
    } else {
      $("#too_short1").remove();
    }

    if (th.contains('\'') || th.contains('\"') || th.contains('\\') || th.contains('\/')) {
      $('#result1').css('display', 'inline');
      var en = $("#forb_char1").text();
      if (!en) {
        $('#result1').append('<p id="forb_char1">Forbidden characters</p>');

      }
    } else {
      $("#forb_char1").remove();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
 .tooltip {
   position: absolute;
   border: 2px solid red;
   display: none;
   margin-left: 250px;
   background: blue;
   z-index: 1;
   color: white;
 }
 .active
}
z-index:999;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form" method="post">
  <div id="result" class="tooltip"></div>
  <span> Write login: </span> 
  <input id="login" name="login" type="text" />
  <br/>
  <div id="result1" class="tooltip"></div>
  <span> Write pwd: </span> 
  <input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="text" />
</form>
<!-- How to addClass active to proper div.tooltip? -->
```

Comment: Yes, using IDs is not the only way for selecting elements. jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors. You have many options. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? :

http://jsfiddle.net/9n2db67u/22/

Your code is very messy. Try to use TidyUp when posting jsfiddle links..

```
$('input').on('click', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).prevAll('div').addClass('active'); //.css('z-index', '20000');
});
```

Comment: I didn't know that there's an option like TidyUp. Thank you, that's all I was looking for.